# Make JsonDeserializer global effect

Tags: json, gson

When deserialize `json` to `Map<out Any, Any>`, gson will use `Double` to fill the `Map`, even the field is int `number`, so I use a `MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix` to covert `number` to `int` if it is possible.

```
{
    "person":{
        "name":"jack",
        "age":24,
        "height":174.5
    }
}
```

```
class MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix: JsonDeserializer<Map<out Any, Any>> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): Map<out Any, Any>? {
        return deserialize(json) as Map<out Any, Any>
    }

    private fun deserialize(jsonElement: JsonElement): Any? {
        when {
            jsonElement.isJsonArray -> {
                val list: MutableList<Any?> = ArrayList()
                val arr = jsonElement.asJsonArray
                for (anArr in arr) {
                    list.add(deserialize(anArr))
                }
                return list
            }
            jsonElement.isJsonObject -> {
                val map: MutableMap<String, Any?> = LinkedTreeMap()
                val obj = jsonElement.asJsonObject
                val entitySet = obj.entrySet()
                for ((key, value) in entitySet) {
                    map[key] = deserialize(value)
                }
                return map
            }
            jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive -> {
                val prim = jsonElement.asJsonPrimitive
                when {
                    prim.isBoolean -> {
                        return prim.asBoolean
                    }
                    prim.isString -> {
                        return prim.asString
                    }
                    prim.isNumber -> {
                        // Here is what i do
                        // use int or long if it is possible
                        val numStr = prim.asString
                        return if (numStr.contains(".")) {
                            prim.asDouble
                        } else {
                            val num = prim.asNumber
                            val numLong = num.toLong()
                            return if (numLong < Int.MAX_VALUE && numLong > Int.MIN_VALUE) {
                                numLong.toInt()
                            } else {
                                numLong
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

```
object MapTypeToken: TypeToken<Map<out Any, Any>>()
```

```
private val GSON = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MapTypeToken.type, MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix())
        .create()
```

- And when I use `GSON` deserialize json as map, it works.

```
 val map: Map<out Any, Any> = GSON.fromJson(json, MapTypeToken.type)
```

- But when the map is in a data class as a field, the `MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix` not work.

```
data class Test(
    val person: Map<out Any, Any>
)
```

```
val test = GSON.fromJson(json, Test::class.java)
```

So is there any way to deserialize map or filed map ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this to solve.

```
class TestJsonDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Test> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext,
    ): Test {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        val personElement = jsonObject.get("person")
        val person = context.deserialize<Map<out Any, Any>>(personElement, MapTypeToken.type)
        return Test(person)
    }
}
```

```
private val GSON = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MapTypeToken.type, MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Test::class.java, TestJsonDeserializer())
        .create()
```

But if another data class has map, I have to write another `JsonDeserializer` and register it.

Hope there is a better way to make the `MapDeserializerDoubleAsIntFix` work as global.